# Python Counters - summing the number of repeat words in a list

Tags: python

i'm trying to take a count of the number of times each word appears in a list. As such i'm trying to use the Counters module but rather than summing up the words, it is summing up individual letters instead.

Code snippet:

```
from collections import Counter

    wkday = ans.strftime("%A")
    incoming.append([wkday,time])
    mycount = Counter(wkday)
    print mycount
```

More code:

```
with open('temp_dates.csv') as csvfile2:
readCSV2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
incoming = []
for row in readCSV2:
     readin = row[0]
     time = row[1]
     year, month, day = (int(x) for x in readin.split('-'))
     ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
     wkday = ans.strftime("%A")
     incoming.append([wkday,time])
     mycount = Counter(wkday)
     print mycount
     print wkday
with open('new_dates2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
  writer = csv.writer(out_file)
  writer.writerows(incoming)
```

If I use Counters as I have it listed this is what I get:

```
Counter({'e': 2, 'd': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1, 'W': 1, 'y': 1})
Counter({'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'M': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'y': 1})
Counter({'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 's': 1, 'u': 1, 'T': 1, 'y': 1})
Counter({'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 's': 1, 'u': 1, 'T': 1, 'y': 1})
Counter({'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'M': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'y': 1})
Counter({'a': 1, 'd': 1, 'M': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'y': 1})
Counter({'e': 2, 'd': 2, 'a': 1, 'n': 1, 's': 1, 'W': 1, 'y': 1})
```

What I need is this:

```
Monday: 3
Tuesday: 16
Wednesday: 6
...etc
```

The input data (print wkday) looks like this:

```
Tuesday
Monday
Monday
Sunday
Saturday
Saturday
Thursday
Wednesday
Sunday
Sunday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Thursday
Wednesday
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code isn't properly indented and seems to be missing a loop of some sort.

Comment: This isn't complete code. You've gone one level too far, possibly in a `for` loop. Please see how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I added a larger block of code, thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the source file so a complete answer can be provided?

Comment: The input data is already listed in the original comment. The list of "wkday" and a printout of that list is above. Thanks!

Comment: @Justin according to the results of your ``print(wkday)``, ``wkday`` is not a list of day strings.. so its not clear

Comment: Testing this with a list as the given wkday works as expected, I would suspect as the answer below is that wkday is not actually a list, at least not in the manner that you expect.

Comment: if I remember correctly wkday.split() should ensure this becomes a pythonic list, correct? Even if I do that (or use splitlines) it still just counts each line rather than the list as a whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `mycount` outside the `for` loop and increment the value for each weekday:

```
# Initialize mycount
mycount = Counter()
with open('temp_dates.csv') as csvfile2:
    readCSV2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
    incoming = []
    for row in readCSV2:
        readin = row[0]
        time = row[1]
        year, month, day = (int(x) for x in readin.split('-'))
        ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        wkday = ans.strftime("%A")
        incoming.append([wkday,time])
        # Increment count for weekday
        mycount[wkday] += 1
```

Comment: ha, that's it! If I initialize mycount outside the loop and then print outside the loop it works as expected. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

According to the results of `print(wkday)` probably your `wkday` is simply a string with days separated by `"\n"`. Split it on words before passing to `Count`

```
wkday = wkday.splitlines()

>>> print(wkday)

['Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Monday', 'Sunday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday', 'Sunday', 'Sunday', 'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday', 'Wednesday']

>>> mycount = Counter(wkday)
>>> print(mycount)

Counter({'Sunday': 3, 'Wednesday': 3, 'Tuesday': 2, 'Monday': 2, 'Saturday': 2, 'Thursday': 2})
```

this confirm my hypothesis of your `wkday` type and  reproduces what you had

```
>>> print(Counter("\n".join(wkday)))

Counter({'d': 17, 'a': 16, 'y': 14, '\n': 13, 'u': 9, 'e': 8, 'n': 8, 's': 7, 'S': 5, 'T': 4, 'r': 4, 'W': 3, 'M': 2, 'o': 2, 't': 2, 'h': 2})
```

Comment: Doing that results in a single count per line:
     
    Counter({'Sunday': 1})
    Counter({'Sunday': 1})
    Counter({'Sunday': 1})
    Counter({'Thursday': 1})
    Counter({'Wednesday': 1})
    Counter({'Monday': 1})
    Counter({'Tuesday': 1})

Comment: @Justin its not clear from your code what is type of ``wkday`` which you pass to ``Counter``. Just make sure that you are passing the list of day string and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed all of your input data to Counter(), e.g.

```
input_data = ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday"]
day_count = Counter(input_data)
print(day_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to aggregate the solution that David Cullen provided along with another snippet of code I needed for formatting, here is the final version:

```
mycount = Counter()
with open('temp_dates.csv') as csvfile2:
  readCSV2 = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
  incoming = []
    for row in readCSV2:
         readin = row[0]
         time = row[1]
         year, month, day = (int(x) for x in readin.split('-'))
         ans = datetime.date(year, month, day)
         wkday = ans.strftime("%A")
         incoming.append([wkday,time])
         mycount[wkday] += 1
with open('new_dates2.csv', 'w') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(incoming)
csvfile2.close()

for key,value in sorted(mycount.iteritems()):
    daylist = key, value
    print(daylist)
```

This allows me to print daylist which looks like this:

```
('Friday', 13)
('Monday', 11)
('Saturday', 7)
('Sunday', 9)
('Thursday', 12)
('Tuesday', 13)
('Wednesday', 12)
```